# Multi-label Classification without any training data

Tags: classification, multilabel

How can I perform multi-label classification without any training data i.e. just using candidate labels like ***zero-shot-learning***? I was able to perform single label classification using only candidate labels (and no training data at all) but not sure how to do the same for multi-label.

Comment: Can you clarify your question about what kind of data you are using and how you did what you did already? Are we talking about natural language processing? Did you use a technique like predicting a word in "This text describes a <MASK> review." and trying out whether "positive" or "negative" is predicted to fit better in place of the MASKED value? That seems to extend to multi-label by e.g. adding an option like "neutral".

Comment: @Björn since you asked about the work I already did on single label classification, I added labels like trouble, issues, error to be identified as **problem** and labels like order, demand and asking to be identified as **request**. The problem occurs when I want a combination query to fall under both {request and problem} or {request and request} or {problem and problem} depending on the query. The thing is I am using segmentation (using standford-nlp) before doing this to segment a query into a single sentence but assuming sometimes it does fail, I need to do multi-label for certain queries